# Importrange for google sheets with range of value between 100 to 200

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have `importrange` code working and pulling the data

`=filter( importrange("File","Sheet1!A:J"),(importrange("File","Sheet1!G:G")=1),(importrange("File","Sheet1!B:B")<200))`

This imports all the rows that that has value less than 200 in column B.

How can I add a range to my formula that imports only rows in Column B that has value between 100 to 200 ?

2nd question: Can i add blank rows between the importrange ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("File", "Sheet1!A:J")}, 
 "where Col7 = 1 
    and Col2 > 100 
    and Col2 < 200", )
```